# How to delete many items by ID using Node/Express and HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a system of 'Notifications', and I am able to delete each notification one by one using a button on html. However, I want to delete many notifications using a 'clear all' button, but I am not why the different strategies I've tried don't work.

I've tried putting a for loop in the HTML to post through the entire array of Notifications to delete, but that didn't work for me.

I also tried putting in the app.post("/notification/delete/all")... Notification[] or something that clears the array but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I removed the strategies I've tried from the code below, maybe there is a problem with my initial set up.

```
app.post("/notification/delete/:id", async (req, res) => {
   const result = await Notification.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
   res.redirect("back");
 });

 app.post("/notification/delete/all", async (req, res) => {
   res.redirect("back");
 });
```

```
<form action="/notification/delete/all" method="post">
   <button id="clear">Clear All</button>
</form>
</h6>


<% for (var i = 0; i<notification.length; i++) {%>
  <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
     <div class="mr-3">
     <div class="icon-circle bg-primary">
     <i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i>
     </div>
     </div>

<div>
   <div class="small text-gray-500"><%= notification[i].timeStamp %></div>
 <span class="font-weight-bold"><%= notification[i].details %></span>

      </div>
<form action="/notification/delete/<%- notification[i]._id %>" method="post">
 <button id="clear" value='<%- notification[i]._id %>'>Clear</button>
</form>
</a>

<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass all the ids in the delete all form, separated by comma, then in the server, split the ids and delete the items.

```
<form action="/notification/delete/all" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="<%- notification.map(item => item._id).join(',') %>">
    <button id="clear">Clear All</button>
</form>
<% for (var i = 0; i<notification.length; i++) {%>
    <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
        <div class="mr-3">
            <div class="icon-circle bg-primary">
                <i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="small text-gray-500"><%= notification[i].timeStamp %></div>
            <span class="font-weight-bold"><%= notification[i].details %></span>
        </div>
        <form action="/notification/delete/<%- notification[i]._id %>" method="post">
            <button id="clear" value='<%- notification[i]._id %>'>Clear</button>
        </form>
    </a>
<% } %>


app.post("/notification/delete/all", async (req, res) => {
    const ids = req.body.ids.split(',');
    for (const id of ids) {
       await Notification.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    }
    res.redirect("back");
});
```